# Inside window scroll function multiple if else statement with attr() not working

Tags: jquery, if-statement, scroll

How to add multiple `if` or `else` inside window scroll function? You can see the example below.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 850) {

        if (scroll <= 650) {
          $j('.innerimage').attr('src', 'images/side_1.png');
        }


          $j('.innerimage').attr('src', 'images/side_2.png');
   }
});
```

Comment: Use a log statement on your scroll variable and tell me what you see is going on in that fiddle that might show why why your statements are not "working"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Look** at your if statement. If scroll is bigger or equal to 850 then check if it's less than or equal to 650???

This is very basic if statements, still unsure of exactly what you want to achieve then I can only recommend this

```
if(scroll >= 850){
    //Larger or Equal to 850    
} else if(scroll >= 650){
    //More than or equal to 650 LESS than 850
} else if(scroll >= 450) {
    //More than or equal to 450 LESS than 650
}.. BLAH BLAH.... else { };
```

Does this make sense? See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pc6m1oq3/60/)

Comment: in this fiddle it is working perfectly but in my case if  i m using multiple if then only one is working no console error, i  updated my question u can see that

Comment: Because of Syntax errors I put in the Question which you copy and pasted and didn't read https://jsfiddle.net/w80ytcLh/13/